# MySQL Trouble with a query

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table that for example it contain 1000 records. The query that I'm trying to do, is for get some like this:

```
substring_part_name      number_of_warehose     number_of_parts
156                             1                       50
156                             2                      140
156                             3                      300
180                             3                      130
120                             1                       80
120                             2                      300
```

And so obtain the 1000 records.
The trouble is this, the part_name is something like this: `x_156, b_156, d_156, h_120, f_120` and so on. Every part has its corresponding warehouse.
The first column i get it on this way: **distinct(substring(part_name,3)) as substring_part_name**, I only want the last part of the name, How i can obtain that result??

My query is this:
**select distinct(substring(part_name, 3)) as substring_part_name, count(#the number of parts by ware_house), ware_house  from ware_houses
group by substring_part_name;**

Comment: maybe store the data in a more normalized fashion

Comment: sorry i coudn't put an image couse i'm new here :(

Comment: Can you post your query here? Description is not clear.

Comment: That's great. We hate images anyway

Comment: select distinct(substring(part_name, 3)) as substring_part_name, count(#the number of parts by ware_house), ware_house  from ware_houses
group by substring_part_name;

Comment: It seems that I could upload the image

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative integer for the `SUBSTRING` (-3) to get the last three characters.

```
select 
    distinct(substring(part_name, -3)) as substring_part_name, 
    number_of_warehouse, 
    number_of_parts 
from table
```

You can also use `RIGHT`:

```
distinct(right(part_name, 3)) as substring_part_name
```

Comment: Im having trouble with the number of parts, o did something like that, but it not contain all the records

Comment: @user3587187 I don't know what you're looking for. You haven't clearly communicated the problem.